# how to call anonymous functions stored in a static array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, anonymous-function

I'm trying to store anonymous functions in a `static array` property of my class. These functions should be invoked later by their index, but calling

```
self::$arr['index']()
```

just doesn't work, while

```
$a = self::$arr['index'];
$a();
```

does!

This doesn't work:

```
class A {
    private static $func = array('a' => '');
    public function __construct() {
        self::$func['a'] = create_function('$str', 'echo "$str";');
    }
    public function go($str) {
        self::$func['a']($str);  // Call the function directly
    }
}
$a = new A();
$a->go("hooray");  // Outputs "Undefined variable: func"
```

But this does:

```
class A {
    private static $func = array('a' => '');
    public function __construct() {
        self::$func['a'] = create_function('$str', 'echo "$str";');
    }
    public function go($str) {
        $a = self::$func['a'];  // Pass the function name to a variable
        $a($str);               // Call the function via the variable
    }
}
$a = new A();
$a->go("hooray");  // Outputs "hooray"
```

**Why?**

I'm using PHP Version 5.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the behavior of php's parser

```
$functionName['a'] = "hello";
self::$functionName['a']();
```

calls

```
self::hello();
```

... the very sad thing is that in php you can't do this:

```
(self::$functionName['a'])(); // doesn't work in php :(
```

as you can do in javascript, for example

what you can do is... use a temporary variable like you said

```
$a = self::$func['a'];
$a($parameter);
```

or

```
call_user_func(self::$func['a'], $parameter);
```

hope this helps...

---

in latest phps these features were added

```
$a['sss'] = function(){ echo 'bla'; };
$a['sss']();

class Bla
{
    private $a;
    function test()
    {
        $this->a['sss'] = function(){ echo 'bla2'; };
        $this->a['sss']();
    }
}
$c = new Bla();
$c->test();
```

and **they work properly**... so for some reason, this syntax doesn't work only when using the scope resolution operator ( ClassName:: self:: etc)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in php you simply can not do that, it is a php feature. But you can use `call_user_func` or its relatives:

```
return call_user_func(self::$func['$a'], $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of how the PHP parser currently works. Since the function call `()` is evaluated before the static operator `::`, you end up with the parser attempting to reference the local variable `$func` instead, and then giving you the error about $func being undefined (which it is, since there is no variable named `$func` in the method).

As you've discovered, you can solve this by doing two separate statements.